# The best way to implement REST in CakePHP 1.3?

Tags: rest, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Does anyone know of any tutorials that explain clearly how to implement simple REST functionality with authorization.

I've seen a few plugins and got also got some basic REST functionality working but there seems no clear guidelines about how to build a secure REST service in Cake.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You don't mention it specifically, but I assume you've looked through [Cake's REST documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1238/REST)?

Comment: Yes I did, and I've implemented the basic REST POST and GET.  All working well.  I'm struggling working out how user authentication fits into the picture.  What headers should I send, how should I get them out?  Is there a simple way to add an API-KEY? etc...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to look into OAuth which uses REST to connect to Web Sevices without sending usernames and passwords.

Try these tutorials for a start

http://code.42dh.com/oauth/

http://www.neilcrookes.com/2010/04/12/cakephp-oauth-extension-to-httpsocket/